# I can't find the correct Model for Invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, invoice

I'm trying to change the invoice model for making changes in invoice pdf but I can't find this.

I'm trying change `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Controller/Abstract.php` and `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php` but I can delete these files and everything works the same.

I searched in my local folder and community and I can't find what are overriding these files.

If I delete all `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/` folder (except the folder `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/`) all works. Why does everything work if I delete the files?

Comment: Compilation is enable in your webshop?

Comment: Yes When I use the compilation it works!! But I don't not why. The compilation is enabled but until I've run it manually it has not worked.

Comment: Please disable the compilation while development and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the compilation while development.